# How to detect whether elasticsearch has enabled dynamic field

Tags: elasticsearch, mapping

I don't know whether my index has enabled/disabled dynamic field. When I use get index mapping command it just responses these informations:

```
GET /my_index1/_mapping
```

```json
{
    "my_index1": {
        "mappings": {
            "properties": {
                "goodsName": {
                    "fields": {
                        "keyword": {
                            "ignore_above": 256,
                            "type": "keyword"
                        }
                    },
                    "type": "text"
                },
                "auditTime": {
                    "type": "long"
                },
                "createUserId": {
                    "type": "long"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't explicitly set the `dynamic` to `false` or `strict`, it will be `true` by default. If you explicitly set that, you will see that in your mappings:

```json
{
    "mappings": {
        "dynamic": false,
        "properties": {
            "name": {
                "type": "text"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And when you index the following document:

```json
{"name":"products", "clickCount":1, "bookingCount":2, "isPromoted":1}
```

Only the field `name` will be indexed, the rest won't. If you call the `_mapping` endpoint again, it will give you the exact mappings above.